# How do you use a row from one table as a property in another table using Datamapper?

Tags: datamapper, ruby-datamapper

The specific instance I am referring to is here. I want to use a row from the Grid table to be the value of the Grid property in the Driver table. But I cannot get updates in the Grid table to persist through to the Grid property on the Driver table
I want to use a row from the Race table to be the value of the Race property in the Driver table.

Here is the code for the datamapper stuff.

```
require "rubygems"
require "json"
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/reloader"
require "sqlite3"
require "data_mapper"

DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/season.db")


class Driver
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, String, :key => true
    property :ptd, Integer
    property :races, Integer
    property :grid, Object
    property :race, Object
    property :hcScore, Integer
    property :domScore, Integer
end

class Grid
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, String, :key => true
    property :AUS_Q, Integer
    property :MAL_Q, Integer
    property :CHI_Q, Integer
    property :BAH_Q, Integer
end

class Race
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, String, :key => true
    property :AUS_R, Integer
    property :MAL_R, Integer
    property :CHI_R, Integer
    property :BAH_R, Integer
end

class Team

    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, String, :key =>  true
    property :domScore, Integer
    property :drivers, Object
end

DataMapper.finalize.auto_migrate!
```

In irb I will do something like

```
irb(main):001:0> require "./season.rb"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> v = Driver.create id: "VET"
=> #<Driver @id="VET" @ptd=nil @races=nil @grid=nil @race=nil @hcScore=nil @domScore=nil>
irb(main):003:0> g = Grid.create id: "VET"
=> #<Grid @id="VET" @AUS_Q=nil @MAL_Q=nil @CHI_Q=nil @BAH_Q=nil>
irb(main):004:0> v.grid = Grid.get "VET"
=> #<Grid @id="VET" @AUS_Q=nil @MAL_Q=nil @CHI_Q=nil @BAH_Q=nil>
irb(main):005:0> v.save
=> true
irb(main):006:0> g.update(:AUS_Q => 6)
=> true
irb(main):007:0> v
=> #<Driver @id="VET" @ptd=nil @races=nil @grid=#<Grid @id="VET" @AUS_Q=nil @MAL_Q=nil @CHI_Q=nil @BAH_Q=nil> @race=nil @hcScore=nil @domScore=nil>
irb(main):008:0> Grid.get "VET"
=> #<Grid @id="VET" @AUS_Q=6 @MAL_Q=nil @CHI_Q=nil @BAH_Q=nil>
irb(main):009:0> AUS_Q = 6 in the Grid table but in the Driver table it continues to be nil!
```

As you can see - AUS_Q in the Driver table continues to be nil even though I set it to be 6 in the Grid table.

Chances are I am doing it wrong and there is an easier way to do this. I encourage all corrections and smackdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use `belongs_to` to create association between resources, and that you use an identity map, like this:

```rb
require "sqlite3"
require "data_mapper"

class Driver
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, String, :key => true
    belongs_to :grid, :required => false
end

class Grid
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, String, :key => true
    property :AUS_Q, Integer
end

DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/season.db")
DataMapper.finalize.auto_migrate!

DataMapper.repository(:default) do
  v = Driver.create id: "VET"
  g = Grid.create id: "VET"
  v.grid = Grid.get "VET"
  v.save
  g.update(:AUS_Q => 6)
  puts v.grid.AUS_Q
  puts Grid.get("VET").AUS_Q
end
```

Everything you do within the block initiated by `DataMapper.repository(:default) do` will use an identity map. Thus, identical objects in the database will result in identical objects in memory.

Comment: When you use a belongs_to doesn't it need a subsequent has n on the table it is linking to?
Also, what is the advantage of making this association. I cannot see how the DataMapper.repository block would use this relationship.

Comment: You add `has n` to the other table only if you need. The advantage of making the association is that you're mapping a real association (which actually exists) to a DM association, thus taking full advantage of DM. That block is there to make sure that identical objects in the database correspond to identical objects in memory -- which means that when you change `AUS_Q` in a `Grid` object, a `Driver` object associated to it will see the change.

Comment: This is a good answer. Sorry it took me so long to come back to it!